# Can anyone provide me with copies of JCLBaseExpert280.bpl and 6 other BPLs - dont seem to be provided by the JCL installer program and wont build

Tags: jedi

Moving to RAD Alexandria - clear all - install.bat doesnt work but loading the install project, compiling it and running it does so JCL 'appears' to be installed. Unfortunately whenever you then load Alexandria it gives 7 bpls not found and they are nowhere on my system.  If I try to build them from D28 they fail to build with other packages missing.  The 7 BPLs missing are JCLBaseExpert280.bpl; JCLDebugExpert280.bpl;  JCLFavoriteFoldersExpert280.bpl, JCLProjectAnalysisExpert280.bpl, JCLRepositoryExpert280.bpl, JCLSIMDViewExpert280.bpl, JCLStackTraceViewerExpert280.bpl.  Because these are missing I cant build JVCL Installer so I'm stuck.  (Unfortunately there is no sign of JVC and JVCL in the packages Getit will install in Alexandria unlike Sydney when it worked like a dream.

Have cleared out all mention of JVC and JVCL from the registry before trying to install and run Clean.bat in both the latest (daily) downloads